# Open interval or closed interval for monotony/curvature of a function

Tags: functions

This is a question, of what would be "formally more correct".

Let's assume I have a random function, say $f(x)=x^3-3x^2-9x+27$.

This function has the extremes $P=(3|0)$ -> local minimum, $Q=(-1|32)$ -> local maximum. An extreme means a shift in monotony ($-$ the slope of the tangent line is equal to $0$ there).

If I want to write down, where this function is (strictly) monotonically increasing/decreasing, how should I go about this?

Should I write

$(-\infty, -1)$ - strictly monotonically increasing (open interval)

OR

$(-\infty, -1]$ - monotonically increasing (half-open interval).

What seems more intuitive to you?

Comment: strictly increasing gives more information

Comment: Yes, that's true. But then I would exclude the extreme value in the interval. What would I do for the extreme of -1 then?

Comment: list it as a turning point and extremum

Comment: Good point - then every case is covered. Thanks!